# GKE ingress path mapping can't handle url params

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am running an ingress in GKE. I am routing most of my traffic to one backend but I wish some calls to be routed to another backend. The ingress looks something like this:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: zone-search
                port:
                  name: external
            path: /api/v2/zones/location-search
            pathType: Prefix
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: api-service
                port:
                  name: external
            path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

If I do a request like `GET /api/v2/zones/location-search`, it works fine.

However, if I do `GET /api/v2/zones/location-search?foo=bar` my request ends up in the api-service backend and not the zone-search as I expected.

I have tried using `pathType: ImplementationSpecific` and had both `path: /api/v2/zones/location-search` and `path: /api/v2/zones/location-search/*` but still no progress. Google requires wildcard to follow a slash but `location-search` is the endpoint itself and has no slash after it.

I also tried using a default backend with the same result. The problem still seems to be that the url including `?foo=bar` doesn't match the path i specified.

I can't do `path: /api/v2/zones/*` since there are other endpoints in the api that would go to the zone-search backend that isn't supposed to.

**Update**

I tried using double quotes, plus removing the second

```
    - http:
        paths:
```

and started getting `failed_to_pick_backend` errors. It ended up solved by changing the health check for the backend service.

I don't know if the health check problem meant that the api-service was selected as a backup when the zone-search service was unhealthy or if one of my two changes solved my initial problem.

Comment: It definitely should work as you expected. I would review if there are any other Ingress affecting (maybe old versions). Also try using double quotes with your paths.

Answer (score -1):

Name-based virtual hosts support routing HTTP traffic to multiple host names at the same IP address. You can use [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer/?hl=zh-TW#remarks) to reuse the load balancer for multiple domain names, subdomains, and to expose multiple services on a single IP address and load balancer. Check out the [simple fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) and [name-based virtual hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) examples to learn how to configure Ingress for these tasks.

Note: Always modify the properties of the Load Balancer via the Ingress object. Making changes directly on the load balancing resources might get lost or overridden by the GKE Ingress controller.

On the other hand :
Each external HTTP(S) load balancer or internal HTTP(S) load balancer uses a single URL map, which references [one or more backend services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services). One backend service corresponds to each Service referenced by the Ingress.

Additionally, to create an Ingress that specifies rules for routing requests depending on the URL path in the request. When you create the Ingress, the GKE Ingress controller creates and configures an external HTTP(S) load balancer, see the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#create-ingress).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, it is very broad and doesn't address my specific query. Do you possibly know where to find a more detailed documentation of how to handle paths? The standard documentation doesn't touch the subject of url parameters.